# Rotating in Gimp using a grid

Tags: picasa, gimp, rotate

In Picasa, when I rotate a picture, I'm shown a grid allowing me to properly align the photo:

[image: Screenshot of picture rotating in Picasa.]

But in Gimp, I can't have the same thing. There is a "grid", but it follows the image (what's the point of that ?):

[image: Screenshot of picture rotating in Gimp.]

Is it possible to have a fixed grid in Gimp when rotating an image ?

Comment: What version of Gimp are you running?

Comment: The point is that you can see how far you rotated your image, there is something to say for both methods

Comment: Gimp 2.6.6, on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the point is that the rotate tool rotate a layer or a selection. Thus if you have other layers, the grid will tell you how your transformation maps to those other layers. I don't think it's possible to have a fixed grid (what would be the point), but you can choose the "direction" of the rotation. The default is "Normal (Forward)". But if you chose "Corrective (Backward)", the image will remain static while the grid rotates. Still not the same thing as in Picasa, but maybe closer to what you want?

Comment: I've scanned a lot of picture, and with a fixed grid I can easily straighten them.

Answer (score 3):

There seem to be two options [backwards and forward rotating](http://world.std.com/~mmcirvin/gimp_tutorial/rotate_crop.html). Check it out and let us know

> When this tool is selected, clicking
>   in the image will superimpose a grid
>   on it that you can rotate by dragging
>   it around. Or, you can select the
>   rotation angle with the slider or text
>   area in that "Rotation Information"
>   box. Clicking on the "Rotate" button
>   will rotate the picture according to
>   the grid.
>
> This tool has a bunch of options, most
>   of which you can ignore. The really
>   important and clever one is "Transform
>   Direction".
>
> When the Transform Direction is
>   "Forward (Traditional)", the grid's
>   orientation represents what the
>   picture will be rotated to from its
>   original upright position. If the
>   picture is already upright and you
>   want it to look tilted, that's the way
>   to do it.
>
> The "Backward (Corrective)" direction
>   is what you use to fix a picture that
>   you took with a tilted camera. You
>   orient the grid so it shows how you
>   think the picture is tilted. I've
>   selected that, and oriented the grid
>   so that it coincides with the tilt of
>   the bookshelf behind Niobe's head.
>   Clicking on Rotate will then un-tilt
>   it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the grid is rotated with the image, maybe you should use [guides](http://docs.gimp.org/2.2/en/gimp-pimping.html#id2578270)?